# String indeces must be integers not str

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

```
event = {'records': {'recordId': 1, 'data': 'logHere'}, {'recordId': 2, 'data': 'logHere2'}}
```

I want to print the `recordId` using this loop

```
for record in event['records']:
    print(record['recordId'])
```

I get the `String indeces must be integers not str` error on `print(record['recordId'])`

I understand why I'm getting this error, but I want to know how can I reformat my dictionary so the loop will print the `recordId`. I don't want to change the loop, I want to change the dictionary.

Comment: When you do `for record in event['records']`, you get a view of the keys in the inner dictionary.  It's unclear what you want to accomplish here.

Comment: Yes I know, but I want to change the dictionary to get `{'recordId': 1, 'data': 'logHere'}` instead of the key

Comment: Why are you looping over the outer dict? Is there going to be more than one record like events = {"record": {}, "record2": {}}

Comment: @PeterH Yes there will be more than one record

Comment: @BojanSrbinoski then show us what your *actual* dictionary looks like.

Comment: In that case you should not be using a dict for "records" it should be a list. So it would be Hongyu Wang's answer. `events = {"records": [{'recordId': 1, 'data': 'logHere'}, {'recordId': 2, 'data': 'logHere2'}]}` then use the same for loop you have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the inner dictionary in a list:

```
event = {'records': [{'recordId': 1, 'data': 'logHere'}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
event = {'records': [{'recordId': 1, 'data': 'logHere'},
                     {'recordId': 2, 'data': 'logHere2'}]}
```

Your records should be a list of items:

```
>>> for record in event['records']:
        print(record['recordId'])
    1
    2
>>>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for answering a question! You might want to add a little explanation, (and make sure explanations like `Your records should be a list of items:` are either commented or outside of a codeblock.